# Updating a subclassed UILabel frame within setText: as UILabel does not resize in UITableViewCell until reload of cell

Tags: ios, uilabel, frame, sizewithfont

I have subclassed a UILabel which I intend to use inside many different `UITableViewCell`s.

Within `setText:` I have used `sizeWithFont` to get a dynamic height for the `UILabel`.

This all works great, however, the frame of the subclassed `UILabel` does not change until the  cell is redrawn. How do I overcome this?

**Note:** In the code below, the size will not change when redrawn because of the `if` statement. I took this out for testing and found it worked after being redrawn.

I thought it would need the use of `setNeedsDisplay` or similar, but they do not work either.

Here is the code I am using:

```
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text
{
    if (text != _text) {
        //  Adjust size to fit contents
        //
        CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), CGFLOAT_MAX);
        CGSize predictedSize = [text sizeWithFont:self.font constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:self.lineBreakMode];

        NSLog(@"Predicted size for \"%@\" (width: %f) is %@", text, self.frame.size.width, NSStringFromCGSize(predictedSize));

        CGRect headlineDescriptionLabelFrame = self.frame;

        headlineDescriptionLabelFrame.size = predictedSize;

        NSLog(@"Old frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));

        [self setFrame:headlineDescriptionLabelFrame];

        NSLog(@"New frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));

        _text = text;
    }
}
```

My output looks like this (with the above 'if' turned off):

```
2012-12-19 19:51:23.576 myApp[1099:c07] Predicted size for "Facebook's photo-sharing service Instagram denies that it has changed its privacy policy to allow it to sell users' photos to advertisers." (width: 172.000000) is {170, 75}
2012-12-19 19:51:23.578 myApp[1099:c07] Old frame: {{138, 46}, {172, 49}}
2012-12-19 19:51:23.578 myApp[1099:c07] New frame: {{138, 46}, {170, 75}}
```

**Cell reload here**
**UILabel is resized and shown after this first cell reload**

```
2012-12-19 19:51:30.018 myApp[1099:c07] Predicted size for "Facebook's photo-sharing service Instagram denies that it has changed its privacy policy to allow it to sell users' photos to advertisers." (width: 172.000000) is {170, 75}
2012-12-19 19:51:30.018 myApp[1099:c07] Old frame: {{138, 46}, {172, 49}}
2012-12-19 19:51:30.019 myApp[1099:c07] New frame: {{138, 46}, {170, 75}}
```

**Cell reload here**

```
2012-12-19 19:51:32.014 myApp[1099:c07] Predicted size for "Facebook's photo-sharing service Instagram denies that it has changed its privacy policy to allow it to sell users' photos to advertisers." (width: 170.000000) is {170, 75}
2012-12-19 19:51:32.014 myApp[1099:c07] Old frame: {{138, 46}, {170, 75}}
2012-12-19 19:51:32.015 myApp[1099:c07] New frame: {{138, 46}, {170, 75}}
```

***EDIT***

After 4 days of trying to figure it out, I'm still having problems with this, does anyone know if this is a bug on Apple's side? How do other people resize a UILabel loaded from a UITableViewCell nib, inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: Did you try with `setNeedsLayout` ?

Comment: Yeah, still the same problem though

Comment: Is there anyway to 'bump' this question, I can't find how to fix the issue anywhere

Comment: Also, I have built the UITableViewCell in Interface Builder. The initial height is the one used in IB, then, when the cell is redrawn back on to screen, the correct height is shown, even though its frame says it was set to the correct height initially

Comment: What does your `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` look like?

Comment: It returns the float '130.0f' (This is the height of the cell, which is big enough to hold all of the cells contents)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ‘cell reload here‘, just try

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

to trigger recalc. of the cells' heights without really reloading them, which is unnecessary since you changed just the label's text.

Comment: Thanks for a reply, my cells are being 'reloaded' when I scroll the tableView not with code. If I were to implement your code, where would be the best place to put it?

Comment: As I said, instead of `cell reload here` in the code you pasted.

Comment: Do you mean within the `setText:` method? This doesn't work. N.B. The code I pasted above with `Cell reload here` is output from the log

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, all I needed to do was add the frame changing code to `layoutSubviews` (as well as the super method `[super layoutSubviews]`.